# success and error function in the controller for a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http, angular-promise

I have the following code in a service and I am calling fetchData function from the controller.

**Service**

```
app.service("geturl", function($http) {
    urllist = [];
    geturl.fetchData = function() {
        var data = [];
        for (i = 0; i < urllist.length; i++) {
          (function(index) {
            return $http.get(geturl.urllist[index], {
              timeout: 8000
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              data[index] = response.data;
            });
          }(i);
          return data;
        });
    };
});
```

I want to write the success and error function of $http.get in the controller since it is needed in the UI, how can I go about it?

Comment: Use angular's promises https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..I want to write the success and error function of $http.get in the
>   controller..

Usually, the `.then()` function takes two function arguments. The first argument is the success handler and the second as an error handler.

```
$http.get(url,options).then(function (response){
    //success handler function
    },function(error){
  //error handler function     
  })
```

Alternatively, you can specify the `.success` and `.error` functions separately.

```
$http.get(url,options).success(function (response){
    //success handler function
    }).error(function(error){
  //error handler function     
  })
```

**UPDATE:**
From your code, it seems that you intend to return something from your service `geturl` and providing the callbacks there itself. This is not how it is supposed to be done. You should return a promise from your service .

```
   ... 
   app.service("geturl",function($http){
     ...
     getData:function(){
        return $http.get(url,options);
     }
     ...               
   });
   ...
```

and handle the success/error callbacks in the module where you are *consuming the service*

```
geturl.getData().success(function(){
//handle success
}).error(function(){
//handle error
})
```

In case you need to make multiple http requests, **never ever use the for loop** . Remember, everything is asynchronous and you are not guaranteed to get the response from one of the previous request before you make a new one. In such scenarios, you should use [$q service](http://%20docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). See @pankajparkar's answer for more details

Comment: In addition, if you return the promise from `$http.get()` to the controller then you can use the `then(function() {})`. If you want to manipulate the data before you send it to the controller then you can return `then(function () {})` because it returns a promise.

Comment: @CallumLinington OP wants something different..he want data after all ajax gets completed..look at mine answer..

Comment: @CallumLinington: Exactly. I have updated the answer. Seems like OP asked something else while he was trying to achieve something completely different. Thankfully pankajparker's answered it pretty well

Comment: @CallumLinington: When I am using done(function(){}), with promise I am getting an error. How can I resolve that?

Comment: use, `then(function () {}, function () {})`, the first parameter is the success function, the second is the error function.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to return a data after all the ajax gets completed, You could achieve this by using `$q.all()`

**Service**

```
app.service("geturl", function($http, $q) {
    this.urllist = [];
    this.fetchData = function() {
        var data = [], promises = [];
        for (i = 0; i < urllist.length; i++) {
          (function(index) {
            var promise = $http.get(geturl.urllist[index], {
              timeout: 8000
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              data[index] = response.data;
            });
            promises.push(promise); //creating promise array
          }(i);
        };
        return $q.all(promises).then(function(resp){ 
            return data; //returning data after all promises completed
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I was not sure weather to answer OP's original query or correct the given code. Thanks your answer saved me a couple of minutes from typing. Kudos

Comment: @NLN Thanks dude.. I think your answer only covered `I want to write the success and error function of $http.get in the controller..` this part that's why I wrote an answer :p

Comment: $q.all() will fail if even one of the requests fail. Is there any way I can execute the then function even if individual requests fail?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that $q.all(promises).then(function(data){// some logic}); It's not entering the then function even if one of the ajax call fails.

Comment: @user2851669 sorry for my bad.. you need to decorate $q service inorder to allow next promise to promise even if the previous promise fails . do look at this http://www.codeducky.org/q-allsettled/

Comment: @user2851669 oh thats nice..should I add it to mine answer..?could you upvote please if it does helped you..THnaks :)